# <nuxt-img/> Is not working with v-bind:src coming from an API response

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The [documentation](https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img#usage) mentions that I can use `<nuxt-img/>` like I'm using the HTML's `<img>` tag however this is not the case.
I have made this example to demonstrate that `<img>` tag is working just fine while `<nuxt-img/>` is not displaying the image.

This is the code:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <pre>{{ pokemon.sprites.front_shiny }}</pre>
    <h1>Normal Image Tag</h1>
    <img class="normal-img-tag" :src="`${pokemon.sprites.front_shiny}`" />
    <h1>Nuxt Image Tag</h1>
    <nuxt-img
      class="nuxt-img-tag"
      placeholder="/images/lazy.jpg"
      :src="`${pokemon.sprites.front_shiny}`"
    />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    pokemon: {},
  }),
  async fetch() {
    this.pokemon = await this.$axios.$get(
      "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard"
    );
  },
};
</script>
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  target: 'static',
  head: {
    title: 'nuxt-img',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxt/image',
  ],
  image: {
    domains: ['localhost']
  },
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/',
  },
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "nuxt-img",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.7.1"
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot

[image]

that showns that `Image` is the lazy load image specified inside `nuxt-img` so nuxt-image is actually working but `:src` is not.

**UPDATE**
I have added  :

```js
image: {
  domains: ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com'],
}
```

to my `nuxt.config.js` as @kissu mentioned but I get this error on console :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_ipx/_/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/6.png 500 (IPX Error (500))
```

and in terminal this error :

```
ERROR  Not supported                                                                                                                                                                 11:21:15  

  at getExport (node_modules\ohmyfetch\cjs\node.cjs:1:54)
  at Object.fetch (node_modules\ohmyfetch\cjs\node.cjs:2:47)
  at Object.http (node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:142:38)
  at node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:445:33
  at Object.src (node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:69:25)
  at _handleRequest (node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:521:25)
  at handleRequest (node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:549:10)
  at IPXMiddleware (node_modules\ipx\dist\shared\ipx.eadce322.cjs:565:12)
  at call (node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
  at next (node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
  at next (node_modules\connect\index.js:161:14)
  at WebpackBundler.middleware (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2194:5)
```

**PROJECT REPO ON GITHUB :**

https://github.com/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/nuxt-img-test

Am I doing something wrong or it actually does not work this way?

Comment: The setup so far looks great. Upgrade to Node v16, delete all the `node_modules`, install everything back. Delete the `.nuxt` directory and try again. Otherwise, feel free to check with a brand new repo (if you can reproduce that one) + check your network or alike.

Comment: The github repo that you shared works on my side. The issue is not the Github repo itself.

Comment: @kissu Indeed the problem is because of my node version. I have tried with node 16 and it worked, the Image size got bigger from 1.3kb to 1.9kb tho  so I don't know how convenient it is to use ```nuxt-img``` but at least it works.
thank you!

Comment: it's interesting that in the docs they mentioned node v12 as a working version,
 
source: https://image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation#troubleshooting

Comment: "Ensure using LTS version of NodeJS", latest LTS is node v16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work if you try with the following

```html
<template>
  <main v-if="!$fetchState.pending">
    <pre>{{ pokemon.sprites.front_shiny }}</pre>
    <h1>Normal Image Tag</h1>
    <h1>Nuxt Image Tag</h1>
    <nuxt-img class="nuxt-img-tag" :src="pokemon.sprites.front_shiny" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pokemon: {},
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.pokemon = await this.$axios.$get(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/charizard'
    )
    console.log('poke', this.pokemon)
  },
}
</script>
```

You need to have that one in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  modules: ['@nuxt/image', '@nuxtjs/axios'],
  image: {
    domains: ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
}
```

since it's referring an external website.

> To enable image optimization on an external website, specify which domains are allowed to be optimized.

Here is the doc related: https://image.nuxtjs.org/api/options#domains

Comment: it is giving me the following error: ```Cannot find module 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/6.png'``` on both suggestions

Comment: @MrXQ updated my answer. Sorry I forgot that the package is doing the heavy lifting in terms of loading. My previous example was for a local image in the project.

Comment: pardon my late replay, 
I have specified the domain URL but still not displaying with the following error :  ```6.png:1          GET http://localhost:53205/_ipx/_/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/6.png 500 (IPX Error (500))```


My ```nuxt.config.js``` looks like this:


 ```image: {

    domains: ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com','localhost']

  },```

Comment: @MrXQ your code properly works on my side (tried it yesterday). Remove `baseURL` (doesn't bring anything to the table here) + remove the `localhost` here since we're not using local images but remote ones and let's see if that fixes the issues.

Comment: I have updated my question because of the comments' limited characters and formatting.
is this error related to my ```node``` version? I'm using ```v12.14.1```

Comment: @MrXQ I've added my full working example setup. I do run on the latest LTS on Node too (v16) so upgrading that one could be a start but I'm not sure that the error is coming from there exactly. Maybe another package that you're using there? Do you have a `package.json` or even better, a public github repo to share there?

Comment: @MrXQ node v12 is indeed quite dead, same goes for v14 btw. And comments are not a good place for code/long messages anyway, prefer a question edit like you just did.

Comment: I will upgrade to version 16 and retry, also I have added the repo link.

Answer (score 1):

In your `nuxt.config` you've specified [domains](https://image.nuxtjs.org/api/options#domains) option for image module. Add your API domain to the array

Comment: pardon my late replay, I have specified the domain URL but still not displaying with the following error:
 ```6.png:1 GET http://localhost:53205/_ipx/_/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/6.png 500 (IPX Error (500))```